# Function not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have this function:

```
Tickets.prototype.each = function(func) {
    _.each(this.getTickets(), func);
};

Tickets.prototype.findWhere = function(key, val) {
    this.each(function(ticket) {
        if(ticket.get(key) === val) {
            console.log(ticket);
            return ticket;
        }
    });
};
```

Then I am calling findWhere here:

```
console.log(this.collection.findWhere('ID', $ticketRow.data('id')));
```

When I run it, the console.log in side of .findWhere prints the correct ticket object.. But the console.log where I am calling it prints 'undefined'.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You're not returning anything to the outer function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to

```
Tickets.prototype.findWhere = function(key, val) {
    var tick;
    this.each(function(ticket) {
        if(ticket.get(key) === val) {
            console.log(ticket);
            tick = ticket;
        }
    });
    return tick;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Tickets.prototype.each = function(func) {
    $.each(this.getTickets(), func);
}; 

Tickets.prototype.findWhere = function(key, val) {
    var tick;
      this.each(function(ticket) {
            if(ticket.get(key) === val) {
                console.log(ticket);
                tick = ticket;
                return false; //break out of .each 
            }
      });
     return tick;
 };
```

You cannot break out of `_.each`, you can only break of `$.each` (if you use jquery).